# C# - How do I prevent duplicate results in nested loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, for-loop

This is part of my code, I want to add to **finalSorted** the two values from **arrFinal** that share the same url (this is what I get with the Split as **line[5]** and **zLine[5]**), and I want them to be one above the other. I try to compare if they are not exactly the same entry by comparing **line[1]** and **zLine[1]** that stores a *REQUEST* or *RESPONSE*. But this part is problematic too, because it returns the same result, not the one with **line[1]** different than **zLine[1]**.

The problem is that I want to compare each iteration of the first loop with all other iterations (second for loop) to check if they match and return, one above the other, the two that have the same url but different field for *RESPONSE* and *REQUEST*.

```
List<string> finalSorted = new List<string>();
    
for (int i = 0;i < arrFinal.Count; i++)
{
    string[] line = arrFinal[i].Split(";");
    for (int z = 0; z < arrFinal.Count; z++)
    {
        string[] zLine = arrFinal[z].Split(";");
        if (line[5] == zLine[5] && line[1] != zLine[1])
        {
            finalSorted.Add(arrFinal[i]);
            finalSorted.Add(arrFinal[z]);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated, I'm open to even change entirely the idea for implementing this solution.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

This is what I get:

```
00:00:00.7443;REQUEST;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
00:00:00.7793;RESPONSE;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
00:00:00.7793;RESPONSE;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
00:00:00.7443;REQUEST;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
```

This is what I want:

```
00:00:00.7443;REQUEST;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
00:00:00.7793;RESPONSE;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
```

Comment: It would be useful if you posted example input/test data, and the expected result.

Comment: If it just strings you can use `HashSet<string>` instead of `List<string>`

Comment: Unless you have code within the loop following the `if..else...` block, the `else { continue; }` section serves no purpose.

Comment: can you post one or two lines of data from `arrFinal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// i assume this format in arrFinal
var arrFinal = new string[] { 
    "v0;REQUEST;v2;v3;v4;url",
    "v0;RESPONSE;v2;v3;v4;url",
};

// order by "url" then by "REQUEST or RESPONSE"
var sorted = arrFinal.Distinct().OrderBy(x => {
    // TODO, range check etc...
    var urlPart = x.Split(';')[5];
    return urlPart;
}).ThenBy(x => {
    var requestOrResponse = x.Split(';')[1];
    return requestOrResponse;
}).ToList();
```